# IOS-MOE Proguard w Dependencies

Tags: libgdx, proguard, box2d, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a simple LibGDX project that uses Box2D as a dependency and IOS-MOE to build with gradle. **The project runs on the desktop but reaches an "UnsatisfiedLinkError" when it tries to initiate the World object. It can't load the Box2D dependency.**

I'm about 20 hours deep in this problem and after posting on here and on the LibGDX issues, I found that the problem is with my proguard.append.cfg file. For the life of me I can't find the issue.

Full stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/j9ddNPEh.
proguard.append.cfg: https://pastebin.com/YHARRg7v proguard.append.cfg (in moe module):https://pastebin.com/B4u2dJ3m. Main Class: https://pastebin.com/vhF9DZVb. build.gradle: https://pastebin.com/BwP0gcFM.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.newWorld(float, float, boolean) (tried
```

How can I include com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2D in my proguard so it compiles correctly on IOS?

BTW, I am using LibGDX V 1.9.6 and intel-multi-os 1.4.0.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue on my own. Took me over a week and I got minimal help from others, so this is my makeshift solution. GDX project is not setup correctly with gdx-setup.jar so I forked [this](https://github.com/multi-os-engine/moe-samples-java/tree/moe-master/LibGDXMissileCommand/) github. Got the libraries linked and running by building with ant and maven, and then following [this](https://multi-os-engine.github.io/doc/multi-os-engine/9_game/1_libgdx/libgdx.html) tutorial on getting the app running on Xcode via IOS-Moe.